# Add CRC field using Construct python library

Tags: python, module, crc, construct

I have the following simple protocol frame. For testing I've been assuming a fixed CRC field, but now I need to add the actual CRC computed from the previous bytes in the frame. How to do it? Maybe by nesting structs?

```
MyFrame = Struct("MyFrame", 
                ULInt8("type"),
                ULInt8("IDMsg"),
                ULInt8("totalPackets"),
                ULInt8("numPacket"),
                ULInt8("day"),
                ULInt8("month"),
                ULInt8("year"),
                ULInt8("hour"),
                ULInt8("minute"),
                ULInt8("second"),
                ULInt16("length"),
                Bytes("payload", lambda ctx: (ctx.length - 14)),
                ULInt16("crc")
            )
```

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Data can be checksummed (and even compressed) using the Tunneling API.

https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tunneling.html#compression-and-checksuming

Your protocol frame example can be modified as follows:

```
MyFrame = Struct(
        "body" / RawCopy(Struct(
            "type" / Int8ub,
            "IDMsg" / Int8ub,
            "totalPackets" / Int8ub,
            "numPacket" / Int8ub,
            "day" / Int8ub,
            "month" / Int8ub,
            "year" / Int8ub,
            "hour" / Int8ub,
            "minute" / Int8ub,
            "second" / Int8ub,
            "length" / Int16ul,
            "payload" / Bytes(this.length - 14),
        ),
        "crc" / Checksum(Int16ul,
            lambda data: crc_func(data),
            this.body.data)
)
```

This code is valid for construct v2.10. Unfortunately, yes, you have to use nested structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the CRC field is correct, look at the Validator Adapter.  Override _validate with something like:

```
_validate(self, obj, context):
     return obj.crc == crc(context.type, context.idmsg, . . . )
```

Where crc is your CRC function and you feed in the rest of the arguments using context.

If you want to add another field to the final container, use Value.

```
Value('calculated_crc', lambda ctx: crc(ctx.type, ctx.idmsg, . . . ))
```